# How to visualize the labels from a Point Cloud in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, point-cloud

I have a point Cloud (Las file) and I wolud like to see/visualize the labels (Z values).

[image]

There´s a way to do it in QGIS? (I´m using QGIS version = 3.24)

Comment: Are you asking how to create a label?

Comment: @Erik - What I want is to see/visualise the labels but if it´s possible to create them it will help me as well.

Comment: Have you checked with the QGIS documentation?

Comment: As far as I can see, point-clouds do not have labels (as raster layer do not have labels, either, by the way). At least in my understanding, it would not make sense to label - what, in fact? The individual points of the point cloud? That would result in a real mess of labels.  To be able to show labels, you need a vector layer.